# How to use Pygtk in a C/C++ application?

Tags: python, c, pygtk

I would like to integrate a simple Pygtk window in a C/C++ application (The reason being a previously designed GUI in pyGtk is to be integrated into a bigger GTK+ (in C) application)

I get Segmentation fault error

Here what i did :

=====> In python (tmp.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio

win=Gtk.Window()
win.connect("delete-event",Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

======> In C/C++ (simple.cpp):

i want to just execute that little window

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
   Py_Initialize();

   FILE *fp      = fopen ("tmp.py",   "r+");

   PyObject *mainModule = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");

   PyObject * subModules = PyList_New(0);
   PyList_Append(subModules, PyString_FromString("Gtk"));
   PyList_Append(subModules, PyString_FromString("Gio"));

   PyObject *Gtkstuff = PyImport_ImportModuleEx("gi.repository",NULL,NULL,subModules);

   PyObject *GtkMod =PyObject_GetAttr(Gtkstuff,PyString_FromString("Gtk"));
   PyObject *GioMod =PyObject_GetAttr(Gtkstuff,PyString_FromString("Gio"));

   PyModule_AddObject(mainModule, "Gtk", GtkMod);
   PyModule_AddObject(mainModule, "Gio", GioMod);

   PyRun_SimpleFile(fp,"tmp.py");
   Py_Finalize();
   return 0;
}
```

The way how i compile is :

```
g++ $(python-config --cflags) -o simple $(python-config --ldflags) ./simple.cpp
```

The output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gi/importer.py", line 68, in load_module
    dynamic_module._load()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gi/module.py", line 291, in _load
    overrides_modules = __import__('gi.overrides', fromlist=[self._namespace])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 1502, in <module>
    initialized, argv = Gtk.init_check(sys.argv)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'argv'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 5, in <module>
    win=Gtk.Window()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 415, in __init__
    if not initialized:
NameError: global name 'initialized' is not defined
```

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: python2.7   and for pygtk is version 3

Comment: Please make sure the `Py_SetProgramName` function takes a `char *` argument instead of `wchar_t *`. And please use a C compiler you don't need `g++`. Rename the file to `simple.c` instead of `simple.cpp` and compile it with `gcc $(python-config --cflags) -o simple $(python-config --ldflags) simple.c`

Comment: Iharob , you said make sure Py_setProgramName function is set to char* , but it is already char* ....i recompiled with gcc, and i got the same issue "segmentation fault".....that's dirty statement ain't it? help me out if i'm not seeing the problem...

Comment: No, I said make sure it TAKES `char *` and not `wchar_t *`. It should not crash. You have a lot of code that i don't think you need.

Comment: when one looks at the main's pointer argv[] i see that it is of type char, so it appears that im ignorant. What should be given to PysetProgramName( ????) .  The reason for the code is that an "import Module" is not like a "from Module import Submodule"

Comment: Yes but you leave that part to python. And I asked about the type of `Py_SetProgramName` beacause in python 3 it takes a `wchar_t *`. But given that the name of the program is `simple` it would not be the cause of the problem anyway turn on warnings like this `gcc -Wall -Werror $(python-config --cflags) -o simple $(python-config --ldflags) simple.c` and see what happens.

Comment: I switched the Werror and the Wall on, above i edited the output of execution.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly, the rest of the code doesn't make sense to me, since you can do all the initialization in the python script.

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]); /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();

    FILE *fp = fopen("tmp.py", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        return 2;

    PyRun_SimpleFile(fp, "tmp.py");
    Py_Finalize();

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did not try it with `pygtk` since I don't have any `pygtk` application and hence it is not installed on my system. But a simple  script which imported `numpy` worked properly.

Comment: thanks a lot iharob, that's good news, but the reason for the whole program is the GUI (pygtk). You kept saying give PySetPramName a char*....i lost you there

Comment: You can do all the `pygtk` stuff inside `tmp.py`. Try and see, `PyRun_SimpleFile(fp, "tmp.py")` would execute a python script from a file, it doesn't matter what is there in the script it would be the equivalent to running `python tmp.py` from the command line. And about `Py_SetProgramName` I thought it could be the cause of segmentation fault because `sizeof(wchar_t) != sizeof(char)`

Comment: I tried it as it is...kept slim and simple. But it is the same output as above "a runtime issue" .  I think the problem is Gtk dependencies or initialization. im not sure if you saw the output above

Comment: You are right I didn't follow that output, but those are `pygtk` specific errors, what distribution are you using?

Comment: I mean what linux distribution?

Comment: distribution is Centos 7 , version of python 2.7

Comment: that's what i do... , i can't find anything on the net that was done using the pygtk.

Comment: What you mean? you don't see any errors when running the script directly. And also, can you elaborate on why you want to do this?

Comment: When i compile the python script "responsible for displaying the simple window GUI", it compiles fine under the centos and as i said i have a real pygtk GUI that i want to use with an even bigger GUI application but in C, the bigger application does all these kinda computations that you could say intensive, there is absolutely no judicious reasons to use that kind of things under python due to latency (serious one in fact) even with parallel or multithreading processing. So, it would be an enormous time saving to use the pygtk GUI in C

Comment: Yes but I think that is the wrong way. And you don't compile the script in python, python just interprets it. My Advice would be that you research about extending python with C, in case you worry about performance. You only need to write a Python module in C and call the functions from inside your Python/pygtk application. For instance, pygtk itself is written that way. And you can find many tools to help you like [cython](http://cython.org/) and many others. You just `import` the module and use it from Python.

Comment: Right, i compiled it obviously in the command line... $python file_name.py  ... i see what you are saying about Cython and an even better alternative like Armadillo or Julia languages all together, but these are more the backend stuff, and in my application are the same as the C stuff i'm doing. My problem is the pyGTK being imported to C.